# EXCEL recursividad

Tags: excel, if

Buenas tengo la siguiente consulta, lo que quiero hacer es comparar la diferencia absoluta entra dos columnas, donde una columna esta completa de datos y la otra carece de algunos, por tanto la diferencia absoluta de la columna donde carece sera el mismo dato de la columna de datos. Por tanto me gustaria saber como se programa con IF para analizar de forma recursiva las filas de estas columnas y en las que exista una diferencia abs distinta del mismo valor que tenemos en la primera columna me lo tome en cuenta mientras que el otro no, el proposito final es evaluar un promedio de la diferencia total. gracias ( tengo excel en ingles, pero no creo que importe)

Comment: Por favor, primero comparte lo que has intentado. Gracias.

Comment: A qué te refieres con "Diferencia Absoluta"? coloca algunos ejemplos de los datos que tienes y los datos que esperas obtener

Comment: Amm seria por ejemplo tengo en en D5 el dato 6,5 y E5 el dato 6,4 la diferencia abs seria 0,1.. mientras que en D6 tengo 6,4 y en E6 tengo 6,7 la diferencia absoluta seria 0,3, con absoluta me refiero a que sea positiva

Comment: y en qué datos tendrías una diferencia negativa? Tienes alguna formula con la que estés trabajando actualmente?

Comment: la diferencia negativa seria en los datos en los que la columna E excede al de la D

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cOBOH

Comment: Respondiendo a lo de sstan lo que he intentado es aplicar una funcion sumar.si pero no se como aplicar la restriccion recursiva para que me vaya evaluando todos los datos hacia abajo, y despues de esto tendria que aplicar un contar,if y realizar la division entre estos pero no se bien como escribir el comando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando formulas matriciales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

observa que la imagen tiene al rededor de la formula tiene unas llaves, para que la formula sea matricial deben de tener como parametros matrices y al finalizar la edición de la formula presionar control + alt + enter

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, pero no me funciona aplicar control alt enter, lo modifique y escribi esto  {=SUM(IF(D5:D114<>E5:E114;E5:E114;0))} (tengo excel en ingles)

Comment: debes escribir la formula sin las llaves luego antes de terminar la edición en vez de solo presionar enter presiona control alt enter. las llaves se ven solo en el editor de formulas

Comment: Okey, muchas gracias

Comment: En la versión en inglés se activa con Ctrl + Shift + Enter